# invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) - for implementing a multiplication and exponential operation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have wrote a program to replace the zeros in a number with 5 with a time complexity of Order of logn N base 10. But cpp implementation make some mistake as show under the code snippet.

Code:

```
int convertFive(int n) {
int i = 0, temp = 0;
do{
    if ((n%10) == 0)
        temp = temp+(5*(10**i));
    else
        temp = temp+(n%10*(10**i))
    i++;
    n = n/10;
}while(n/10 != 0);
return temp;
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp:24:33: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
         temp = temp+(5*(10**i));
                             ^
prog.cpp:26:36: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
             temp = temp+(n%10*(10**i))
```

Comment: There is no `**` operator in C++.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Tip: This task is much easier to perform on string than on numbers.

Comment: It's also easier to learn C++ if you don't assume that it does things like Python.   Python and C++ are very different languages so, you know, they don't always do things the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ** operator in C++ (You bring ** operator from python3?) 
Instead of **, you can use pow function included in <del>math.h</del> cmath header.

> double pow(double base, double exponent);

(Ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)

And also, there is no semicolon in the 7th line

Comment: Why not just use `pow`?  Do note that both will introduces floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: I don't know the exact range of i, so I suggest a function that can cover bigger range

Comment: `pow` does that automatically.  If it gets `int`'s, or any integer type for both parameters it spits out a `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `**` operator in C++, but exponentiation is unnecessary anyway.
Instead of repeated exponentiation, multiply by 10 on each iteration.
You also have bug where you ignore the first digit because you're exiting the loop too soon.

```
int convertFive(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    int position = 1;
    do {
        int digit = n % 10;
        if (digit == 0)
            result += 5 * position;
        else
            result += digit * position;
        position *= 10;
        n /= 10;
    } while (n != 0);
    return result;
}
```